# Изменить цвет текста у childView в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

Есть `ExpandableListView` несколько разделов, и у каждого несколько подразделов.
Задача по нажатию на подраздел изменять цвет текста, но только один подраздел может отличаться от других (мы как бы маркируем, какой сейчас выделен объект).
Выделить и изменить цвет получается, но сделать так чтобы только один был выделен не понимаю как. 
И еще в момент onCollapse нужно выделить самый первый подраздел. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно по разному. Например так:

1. Заведите в классе адаптера переменную, коя будет хранить порядковый номер выделенного элемента (в виде массива int - номер группы и подгруппы). Значение по умолчанию назначьте на ваш вкус (т.е. если вам надо, чтоб по умолчанию был выделен (изменён цвет текста) 1 элемент первой группы, то будет {0, 0})
2. При нажатии на элемент запишите номер группы и подгруппы в переменную. Далее вызывайте notifyDataSetChanged() над адаптером.
3. В методе getChildView() (т.е. методе отрисовки элемента подгруппы) сравнивайте его номер группы и подгруппы с переменной из первой группы. Если он совпадает - меняйте цвет, иначе - возвращайте цвет по умолчанию.
4. Переопределите метод onCollapse и в нём устанавливайте нужную вам позицию (группа и подгруппа) в переменную из первого пункта. Вызывайте notifyDataSetChanged().

Таким образом класс адаптера всегда будет знать какой элемент должен быть выделен, при нажатии он будет изменяться (а остальные будут иметь вид по умолчанию).